# Action Could Not Be Found for Controller

Tags: controller, ruby-on-rails-4

Getting my way through a Ruby on Rails tutorial; I know this is very simple, but I'm stumped, as I'm very new to the framework here.

After generating a controller and mapping it appropriate in the .config log, and defining an action in my controller- I'm still receiving the same 'action error' within localhost:3000.

Here is what I am getting:

'Unknown Action'

'The action 'new' could not be found for PostsController'

Controller:

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController
end

def new
end
```

Can anyone shed some light on the issue?

Comment: Can you please post the config/routes.rb file.

Comment: Got it sorted out, thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The controller class is closed before the `new` action is defined. Move the `end` in the second line behind your new action.

Answer (score 1):

Sweet lord I ended up here because my controller method was private (aka was listed below the `private` declaration in the controller).

Comment: Thank you! That was my problem too, your answer helped me!